# Put functions into vector and execute

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to make a vector/deque as function container.

This containter must take diffrent functions with diffrent arguments.

Example functions:

```
program_data::getInstance().function(int,std::string);
program_data::getInstance().foo(int);
program_data::getInstance().exam(int,std::string,double);
```

And could you show example code how to **put** these functions with arguments to std::vector / std::deque and **execute**?

I think that i should use std::function and std::bind but i dont know how to support diffrent functions with diffrent args size.

**With arguments** -> my functions (called `function` `foo` `exam` from `program_data`) do some actions using arguments.

*For example: normally i execute this function:*

`program_data::getInstance().function(10,"halo");`

And now i want to put these functions to `std::vector // deque` and execute with arguments which i put with function. i.e (if i put function above to vector and use (pseudocode) `vector[0].run();` then my program run function `program_data::getInstance().function(int,std::string);`)

Comment: "with arguments" - meaning that you want to create something that, when called, has the same effect as calling the function with the specified arguments?

Comment: You might be looking for lambda expressions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: Are the values of your arguments known at enque time ? Is the return type of your functions always the same?

Comment: Sorry but what mean 'enque' ? - Yes return type is the same -> `void`

Comment: If `std::vector`/`std::deque` can be filled in compile-time, you can simply make a struct holding functions.

Comment: If not... well, you can cast pointers into some type (don't know which), store it, and while reading pointer cast it back (awful solution), or you can switch to Python or JavaScript and do it easily.

Comment: You can only put functions (via pointers) into a `vector` or `deque` if they all have the same number and type of parameters and return value.

Comment: @Thomas Indeed, the question is misleading. it *sounds* like OP wants a vector of function signatures that differ.

Comment: The `vector` and `deque` are homogenous containers - all elements must have same type.  You could use *function objects* as long as they are derived from the same base class.

Comment: @ThomasAndrees with time of enqueue, I mean the moment where your code puts the function into you vector/queue.  Most of the answers  here use constant parameters, that do not change between the moment you put the function into the vector and the moment you execute it.  is this ok for you ?

Comment: @Christophe do you mean send variable as reference ?
`function(int a, std::string &b);`
where b is reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely, use `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` - that is, a vector of type-erased function containers that can hold any object that is callable without arguments:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vector;

// populate the vector
vector.push_back([]{ program_data::getInstance().function(10,"halo"); });

// execute items in the vector
vector[0]();
```

Here I'm populating the vector with a captureless lambda; you can also use lambdas with captures, bind-expressions (`std::bind`), and other callable objects.

If you use a lambda with a capture, you need to ensure that captured variables are either captured by value or have a lifetime that contains that of the collection of callables:

```
std::string tmp;
vector.push_back([&tmp]{ program_data::getInstance().something(tmp); });
```

Comment: Could you show and example when variable is send by reference ?
`std::string tmp;` `program_data::getInstance().function(10,tmp);` where tmp is argument of `std::string &tmp;` Of course when variable is available to access

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;
functions.push_back([](){ program_data::getInstance().function(123, 456, "str"); });
```

This adds one function in your vector 'functions'. By calling `functions[0]()`, this will call the lambda expression which then calls your function with 123, 456 and "str" as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::function`/`std::bind`. So first of all you need to determine what will you pass to those functions from caller side ie determine function signature. The principle is the same as with virtual functions. So for example you want to pass a sequence number (in which order functions are called) and return nothing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function< void( int ) > Function;
typedef std::vector<Function> Functions;


void func1( int seq, const std::string &str );
void func2( const std::string &str );
void func3( int seq );

void run()
{
    Functions functions;
    // populate functions
    functions.push_back( std::bind( func1, std::placeholders::_1, "foobar" ) );
    functions.push_back( std::bind( func2, "foobar too" ) );
    functions.push_back( func3 ); // you can use std::bind here as well, just to show it can be omitted if function signature matches

    // call them
    for( size_t i = 0; i < functions.size(); ++i ) {
        functions[i]( i );
    }
}
```

Benefit of this method, it can be used for pre c++11 compiler with boost.